# TypeScriptでオブジェクトの要素の１つで配列をsortするには

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScriptで例えば

```
type sample {
  x: string;
  y: number;
}
```

のようなtypeを定義して、これを複数持つ次のような配列があった時に、

```
[
  {x: "hello", y: 1},
  {x: "world", y: 5},
  {x: "foo", y: 3},
  {x: "bar", y: 2},
]
```

yの値で小さい方から大きい方に並び替えをして次のようにするにはどうしたら良いでしょう？

```
[
  {x: "hello", y: 1},
  {x: "bar", y: 2},
  {x: "foo", y: 3},
  {x: "world", y: 5},
]
```

どなたか効率の良い方法をご存知ないですか？よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本家SOの[回答のObjectsの項](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21689268)のようにsort関数を使うのが高速で安定したソート方法ではないでしょうか。

```
var objectArray: { x: string; y: number; }[] = [
  {x: "hello", y: 1},
  {x: "world", y: 5},
  {x: "foo", y: 3},
  {x: "bar", y: 2},
];

var sortedArray: { x: string; y: number; }[] = objectArray.sort((n1,n2) => {
    if (n1.y > n2.y) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (n1.y < n2.y) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Comment: `var` の代わりに `let` を使用する お願いいたします。

Comment: それは素晴らしい追加質問ですね！でもここにある情報だけではなぜ`var`を`let`にすると動かないのか分かりません。ぜひこのご質問を別の質問にして、具体的なコードとどこでエラーが出るかを質問で明らかにしてください！その質問はきっと[他の人の役に立ちます](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3345/9820)！

Comment: すみません、私の日本語は基本です。安全のため、TypeScript で Let を使用します

Comment: I'm sorry for my misunderstanding (and broken English)! Your comments are not questions but advices. I know, you're right! Thanks @fredyfx

Comment: ということで、初期化した値を変更せずに固定値を使う変数は[`var`ではなく`let`で宣言しましょう](https://techacademy.jp/magazine/14872)。

Comment: はい!　心配しないで!　どうもありがとうございます